# Passing an object by value and then by reference

Tags: c#, .net, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have the following code:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myclass c = new myclass();

        c.test1 = 1;

        myclass c2 = TestPassByValByRef(c);

        Console.WriteLine("c.Test1: {0}", c.test1);
        Console.WriteLine("c2.Test1: {0}", c2.test1);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static myclass TestPassByValByRef(myclass c)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before NowPassByRef c.Test1: {0}", c.test1);
        NowPassByRef(ref c);
        Console.WriteLine("After NowPassByRef c.Test1: {0}", c.test1);

        return c;
    }

    private static void NowPassByRef(ref myclass c)
    {
        c = new myclass();
        c.test1 = 10;
        c.test2 = 25;
    }
```

The output is that c2 retains the changed value, whereas c does not.
My question is this: What happens to `c` in `TestPassByValByRef`?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `TestPassByValByRef` there are two references to your object - the reference in `Main`, and the reference for the parameter to `TestPassByValByRef`. This is because passing a reference type (anything that isn't a `struct`) in C# 'by value' actually passes the *reference* by value, not the object itself. Thus, the reference is copied and there are now two references to the original object.

After the call to `NowPassByRef`, `TestPassByValByRef`'s copy of the reference has been overwritten by a reference to a new instance of `myclass`, but since there's still the reference in `Main` the object is not eligible for garbage collection.

So, the short answer to "what happens" is "nothing".

Answer (score 0):

In first case you pass **by value** a `reference` to your object.

So when you do *in first case* you make `new`, you reinitialize the **copy** of the `reference`, so it looses the relation with original object.

In second case you pass a `reference` **itself**, so reinitializing it with `new` you change also the memory location where it points.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but many people try to avoid conflating pointers and references, especially in languages where both exist (which includes C#)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: changed to REFERENCE. But not understanding someone post could not be a reason to downvote it, seems to **me**

Answer (score 0):

In your following code you `c = new myclass();` create a new memory reference for `object c` which does not point to the passed.  Due to this you are not getting the changes reflected to your first object that you created.

```
private static void NowPassByRef(ref myclass c)
    {
        c = new myclass();  // it will create new memory reference
        c.test1 = 10;
        c.test2 = 25;
    }
```

so it will show c does not get changed and output as:

```
Before NowPassByRef c.Test1: 1
After NowPassByRef c.Test1: 10
c.Test1: 1
c2.Test1: 10
```

For a while just comment the `c = new myclass();` in the method and it will reflect the changes to the `object c`. it will clear your doubt about the reference pointer etc.

```
private static void NowPassByRef(ref myclass c)
        {
            //c = new myclass();  // it will create new memory reference
            c.test1 = 10;
            c.test2 = 25;
        }
```

Now output will be:

```
Before NowPassByRef c.Test1: 1
After NowPassByRef c.Test1: 10
c.Test1: 10
c2.Test1: 10
```

> I think this -
>   [C# pass by value/ref?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436986/c-sharp-pass-by-value-ref)
>   must be your explained information for your question and check John
>   Skeet's article on [Parameter passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html).

Comment: Just to be clear - what I'm questioning is not why the value is not retaining its changed value, but why IS.  What I expected to happen for this code sample was for the value to remain as was.

Comment: @pm_2: I think you have not ridden answer completely.. I am not focusing on output, just shown you it is changing reference and you need to go through these links...

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    myclass c = new myclass();

    c.test1 = 1;

    myclass c2 = TestPassByValByRef(c);

    Console.WriteLine("c.Test1: {0}", c.test1);
    Console.WriteLine("c2.Test1: {0}", c2.test1);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

`main` contains two references, both of which can refer to objects of type `myclass`. `c` is initialized before `TestPassByValByRef`, `c2` is initialized by the return value of that method.

```
private static myclass TestPassByValByRef(myclass c)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before NowPassByRef c.Test1: {0}", c.test1);
    NowPassByRef(ref c);
    Console.WriteLine("After NowPassByRef c.Test1: {0}", c.test1);

    return c;
}
```

`TestPassByValByRef` contains a single reference called `c`. It initially contains a **copy** of the reference that was passed to it as a parameter (because that parameter was passed by value). *This* reference is then passed by reference to `NowPassByRef` and returned.

```
private static void NowPassByRef(ref myclass c)
{
    c = new myclass();
    c.test1 = 10;
    c.test2 = 25;
}
```

`NowPassByRef` shares a reference `c` with its calling method. It immediately reassigns it to a new value before returning.

---

What did you expect to happen?